# How to Open PPT to PDF C#

Tags: c#, pdf, automation, powerpoint

I have an automation code to generate PDF

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application objApp;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentations objPresSet;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint._Presentation objPres;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slides objSlides;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slide CurSlide;

objApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();

// code stuff to write to PPT slides
```

Now the Export part:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application ppApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
ppApp.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentations oPresSet = ppApp.Presentations;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint._Presentation oPres;

ppApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
oPres = ppApp.Presentations.Open(sourcepath, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse);
oPres.SaveAs(Targetpath, PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsPDF, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue);
```

In export, the code opens any saved PPT but not the current running Presentation. My question is

1) How to open the current PPT as PDF ? `(i.e converting it to PDF before saving it)`

Thank you All

Comment: what if you change `Open line` into this one: `oPres = ppApp.Presentations[1];` which will make your oPres variable referring to first currently open presentation in your PP application.

Comment: You create `ppApp`, create `oPresSet` from it, then create `ppApp` again, and use it to re-create `oPres`. Did you mean to do all that redundant stuff?